# Rails - How to build a custom validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3 form, with data-remote => true.

The form field is handle, like a twitter handle. I want to add validation to ensure it's handle friendly, meaning, no spaces, or non-url friendly characters.

Where to start, do I build a customer validation for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want to use `validates_format_of`

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_format_of :handle, :with => /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/, :message => "Only letters allowed"
end
```

Change the regular expression pattern to match your needs. See the [Rails Guides on validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Look into `validates_each`

```
validates_each :handle do |record,attribute,value|
    # your validation code here, and you can record.errors.add().
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In rails 3 the best practice will be using

`validates :handle, :format => {:with => /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/, :message => "Only letters allowed"}`